# What could be the ideal server side stack for an iOS two-player game?

Tags: ios, node.js, mongodb

I am about to start an iOS two-player game.
Its a card game, and is played turn by turn.

After going through a lot of articles and blog posts,
I have decided to go with these:

node.JS on the backend to respond to API calls.
MongoDB as the database.
and Apples Notification service to push data to other devices.

I am comfortable with JavaScript and I am willing to learn node and mongoDB both and I have some time before the project can start.

I have worked with PHP and Java in the past.

Considering the entire scenario, shall I go ahead with what I have thought or there are things I should consider.

Comment: I would NEVER rely on APNS for a game to send data, it's just far too unreliable...

Comment: Then what could be other alternatives ?

Comment: just use peer-to-peer with game center, for a 2 person game. Much more reliable, allows for player invites, and more.

Comment: Go for it. Beautifully simple with JSON all the way from front to back. It really, really makes dev so much easier, instead of having (in good Java tradition) to create DTO's / values objects / repositories / builders, etc. Of course you need to structure you're Node-app, but without the cumbersome plumbing.

Comment: I am not sure whether to go for HTTP or TCP directly.
HTTP is a lot easier, but for push I rely on APNS.
but with TCP , server can talk to device whenever it wants.
I found a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich, where he uses python with Twisted on server for a two player game.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/4456/how-to-make-a-multiplayer-iphone-game-hosted-on-your-own-server

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider [google app engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/overview) using a java or a python backend as the server side.  The most obvious advantage is that you wont have to worry about infrastructure hassles as GAE is a managed service.  GAE has a high replication datastore similar to mongo and you can code the backend in java which you already know.